# Node.js on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, symfony, ubuntu

I've been writing a Symfony app on Windows, now I am moving it across to an Ubuntu server.

I have been using this:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MyAppAuthenticationBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        less:
            node: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
            node_paths: [C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
```

My question is:

1. How do I install node.exe/node.js on Ubuntu
2. Once it's installed, where should I be pointing the "node" and "node_paths" parameters at?

Thanks

Comment: Does Google not work for you? https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20install%20node%20js *"where should I be pointing the "node" and "node_paths" parameters at"* To the node binary and apparently a directory where your modules are installed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have followed the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server and http://zechim.com/blog/2013/01/10/install-less-and-configure-on-symfony-2/ but when I run `sudo npm install --global less` I get this error: "npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: less". Do you know what that means and how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: It means that npm was unable to get the less module, but I can't tell you why.

Comment: The version of Node is 0.6.12 and npm is 0.6.12, they seem quite outdated to me. How do I ensure I get the most recent package? I used `apt-get install` to install these. Thanks

Comment: You can always compile from source. http://nodejs.org/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu, use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) for up-to-date stable node binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js provides pre-compiled binaries in a handy tarball.  In a shell (with sudo):

```
curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.29-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xzf - --strip-components=1 --directory /usr/local
```

Obviously, plugin the Node.js version you want in that URL, and adjust the path if necessary for your system.